# Effective coulomb interaction Random Phase Approximation: Sum of ring diagrams does not converge

Tags: many-body

To calculate the effective (screened) coulomb interaction $v_{eff}(q,\omega)$ in an electron gas we basically need sum over all Feynman diagrams which have one interaction line with momentum $q$ and energy $\hbar\omega$ entering them and one interaction line with the same energy and momentum leaving them again.

In the random phase approximation we don't sum over all diagrams, but only over ring diagrams, which consist of an interaction line, a ring of two electron lines with momenta $k$ and $k+q$, another interaction line and so on. In this approximation we find

$$v_{eff}(q,\omega) = v(q) + v(q)^2\chi^{(0)}(q,\omega) + v(q)^3(\chi^{(0)}(q,\omega))^2 +... = \sum_{n=0}^\infty v(q)^{n+1}(\chi^{(0)}(q,\omega))^n$$

where $v(q) = \frac{4 \pi e^2}{q^2}$ is the unscreened coulomb interaction and $\chi^{(0)}$ is the electric susceptibility of the free electron gas as given by Lindhards formula.

In all texts I have looked at so far (in particular Nolting: *Fundamentals of Many-Body Physics* and Altland, Simons: *Condensed Matter Field Theory*) this geometric series is now summed to

$$v_{eff}(q, \omega) = \frac{v(q)}{1-v(q)\chi^{(0)}(q,\omega)}$$

However, if  $|v(q)\chi^{(0)}(q,\omega)|>1$ the above series does not converge (it also does not diverge to $\infty$, because $\chi^{(0)}(q,\omega)<0$). This happens if $q$ is below the Thomas-Fermi momentum, and often the formula for $v_{eff}$ is also used for low momenta. Why can we just use this formula even though the series we used to derive it does not converge?